# Injecting HTML after first element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to insert some HTML between two elements, a reduced test case of my code is:

```
<div class="testing">
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
</div>
```

What I want to do is inject the word "or" between the two, so:

```
<div class="testing">
<span>1</span>
<p> or </p>
<span>2</span>
</div>
```

I've looked at using the after and prepend methods but there doesn't seem to be a way to limit it to the first span within a div.

Comment: Is it *always* the first span, or do you know when it will be which number of span?

Comment: Yes in this case it will always be after the first span.

Comment: @user319940 As you can see in the answers this can be achieved with a simple selector. Note how `:first` is just an alias of `:eq(0)`. See the documentation on [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more useful info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('div.testing span:eq(0)').after('<p> or </p>');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EWykY/)**

And as noted in the comments, `span:eq(0)` is also equivalent to `span:first`.

Comment: seems to work great - what does the eq:(0) do? - edit: awesome thanks, will accept this as the answer.

Comment: `.eq()` allows you to pick the index of the element you want. See http://api.jquery.com/eq/. It's zero based, so `.eq(0)` is the first element.

Comment: @user319940 This is a zero-based index, of course. So `:eq(1)` would select the *second* element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.testing span:first').after('<p> or </p>');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.testing span').first().after('<p> or </p>');
```

Comment: As noted in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first/): the `first()` method will `[r]educe the set of matched elements to the first in the set.` So only the very first element in the jQuery object will be returned and *not* the first element matching the selector in each parent element. In other words, this will only append the HTML after only one `span` element and not after all matching `span` elements.